# Output 2 dim array 'list of lists" to text file in python

Tags: python, list, text

Simple question - I am creating a two dim array (`ddist = [[0]*d for _ in [0]*d]`) using lists in the code below. It outputs distance using gis data. I just want a simple way to take the result of my array/list and output to a text file keeping the same N*N structure.  I have used output from print statements in the past but not a good solution in this case.

I am new to python by way of SAS.

```
def match_bg():
    #as the name suggests this function will match the variations of blockgroups with grid travel time. Then output into two arras time and distance. 
    count = -1
    countwo = -1
    ctime = -1
    ddist = [[0]*d for _ in [0]*d] #cratesan N*N array list
    dtime = -1


    while count < 10:
        count = count +1
        #j[count][7] = float(j[count][7])
        #j[count][6] = float(j[count][6])
        while countwo < d:
            countwo = countwo+1
            if count < 1:
                #change values in bg file 
                j[countwo][7] = float(j[countwo][7])
                j[countwo][6] = float(j[countwo][6])




            #print j[count], j[countwo]
            while ctime < RowsT:

                #print ctime,  lenth,  t[ctime][0],  count,  countwo
                ctime = ctime + 1



                #takes both verations of big zone which should be end of the file and matches to travetime file - note 0 and 1 for t[] should be same for different files
                if ((j[count][lenth-1] == t[ctime][0]) and (j[countwo][lenth-1] == t[ctime][1])) or ((j[countwo][lenth-1] == t[ctime][0]) and (j[count][lenth-1] == t[ctime][1])):
                    if t[ctime][0] != t[ctime][1]:
                        #jkdljf
                        x1=3963*j[count][7]*(math.pi/180)
                        x2=3963*j[countwo][7]*(math.pi/180)

                        y1=math.cos(j[count][6]*math.pi/180)*3963*j[count][7]*(math.pi/180)
                        y2=math.cos(j[countwo][6]*math.pi/180)*3963*j[countwo][7]*(math.pi/180)

                        dist=math.sqrt(pow(( x1-x2), 2) +  pow((y1-y2), 2))

                        dtime = dist/t[ctime][11]
                        print countwo,  count
                        ddist[count-1][countwo-1] = dist/t[ctime][lenth]
                        print dtime,  "ajusted time",  "not same grid"

                        print 
                    elif j[count][5] != j[countwo][5]:
                        #ljdkjfs
                        x1=3963*j[count][7]*(math.pi/180)
                        x2=3963*j[countwo][7]*(math.pi/180)

                        y1=math.cos(j[count][6]*math.pi/180)*3963*j[count][7]*(math.pi/180)
                        y2=math.cos(j[countwo][6]*math.pi/180)*3963*j[countwo][7]*(math.pi/180)

                        dist=math.sqrt(pow(( x1-x2), 2) +  pow((y1-y2), 2)) # could change to calculation

                        dtime = (dist/.65)/(t[ctime][10]/60.0)


                        print dtime,  dist, "not in the same bg", j[count], j[countwo],  t[ctime]

                    elif j[count][5] == j[countwo][5]:
                        if t[count][7] < 3000000:
                            dtime = 3
                        elif t[count][7] < 20000000:
                            dtime = 8
                        else:
                            dtime = 12
                        print dtime,  "same bg"
                        print t[ctime][0],   t[ctime],  1,  j[count], j[countwo] 
                    else: 
                        print "error is skip logic",   j[count], j[countwo],  t[ctime]
                    break
                #elif (j[countwo][lenth-1] == t[ctime][0]) and (j[count][lenth-1] == t[ctime][1]):
                    #print t[ctime][0],  t[ctime],  2,   j[count], j[countwo]
                    #break

            ctime = -1

        countwo = -1
```

Comment: Please indent all the code by four spaces so that it can be formatted properly.  For the code in your first sentence, you'll need to delimit it with the backtick character (`).

Comment: oh dear, how is this code relevant to writing output to the file?

Answer (score 6):

that's what you could to output your 2-d list (or any 2d list for that matter):

```
with open(outfile, 'w') as file:
    file.writelines('\t'.join(str(j) for j in i) + '\n' for i in top_list)
```