# Saving output URLs with next line in file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract data from website and have following code which is extracting all URLs from Main category and its sub category links. 
I am now stuck in saving the extracted output with line separator (to move each URL in separate line) in a file -Medical.tsv

Need help on this.
Code is given below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import random

def write_to_file(file,mode, data, newline=None, with_tab=None):   #**
    with open(file, mode, encoding='utf-8') as l:
        if with_tab == True:
            data = ''.join(data)
        if newline == True:
            data = data+'\n'
        l.write(data)

def get_soup(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

url = 'http://www.medicalexpo.com/'
soup = get_soup(url)
raw_categories = soup.select('div.univers-main li.category-group-item a')
category_links = {}

for cat in (raw_categories):
    t0 = time.time()
    response_delay = time.time() - t0 # It wait 10x longer than it took them to respond using delay.
    time.sleep(10*response_delay) # This way if the site gets overwhelmed and starts to slow down, the code will automatically back off.
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,5)) # This will provide random time intervals of 2 and 3 secs acting as human crawl instead of bot.
    soup = get_soup(cat['href'])
    links = soup.select('#category-group li a')
    category_links[cat.text] = [link['href'] for link in links]
    print(category_links)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the write_to_file function but you never call it? mode have to be w or w+(if you wanna overwrite in the case if the file already exists)

Comment: I tried to use it but need help to Print Text and Print URL's separately line by line. Using     write_to_file('Output_Categories.tsv','w', category_title, newline=True, with_tab=True)

Comment: Need help on how to print Text and URL line by line in a single file.

Comment: in your case just 
l.write('hello\n')
l.write('Wordl!') 
would be line 1 hello, line 2 World.
for example if you have a list 
for x in name_of_list:
    l.write(x+'\n')

in case of text and url just merge those to in a 2d list and write it like this 
take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1009764/4857606

Comment: Thanks Tollpatsch I will try this.